# Documenting functions built by a Proxy get trap

Tags: javascript, intellisense, es6-proxy

In https://github.com/draber/fancy-node/blob/main/src/index.js#L242 I use the `get` trap of a `Proxy` to build function names on the fly. That works just fine, but the problem is documentation. I'd like to have IntelliSense in VS Code for instance, but I have no idea on where to start. I'd be grateful for any pointers.

Comment: That seems very inefficient, using a proxy to create a new function on every property access. Why not just create functions for all valid html/svg tag names explicitly?

Comment: There are, depending on how you count, several hundred HTML/SVG elements. Let's optimistically say one function has 50 bytes, so you'll end up with with maybe 20 kb as opposed to the current 2 kb. On top of that you'll have to maintain these functions, add new ones and drop deprecated ones.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case somebody comes with a similar problem in the future, I have found a solution. In my particular scenario I know the names and signatures of all "virtual", i.e. Proxy-generated functions.

A file *index.d.ts* with all function declarations in the same directory where *index.js* (the main entry point) lives solves the issue. VS code uses this file   for IntelliSense but it won't appear in the bundle, so that the file size doesn't change.